How to enable TCP protocol of SQL Server Express 2019 through C# code?
I have SQL Server Express 2019 installed in Windows 11 desktop. I want to enable SQL Server Express TCP protocol programmatically from Windows Application using C#.
So, I have written following simple code.
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;

    ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer();
        ServerProtocol srvprcl = mc.ServerInstances[0].ServerProtocols[2];
        srvprcl.IsEnabled = true;
        srvprcl.Alter();

This code is returning mc.ServerInstances.count = 0, so eventually I am getting error, though this code is running with administrative permission.
To get around I have created following powershell script.
        Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
        Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber -Force
        Import-Module SQLServer -Force


        $wmi = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer

        $Wmi

        $uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='" + (get-item env:\computername).Value + "']/ServerInstance[@Name='SQLEXPRESS']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"

        $Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
        $Tcp.IsEnabled = $true
        $Tcp.Alter()
        $Tcp

With administrative permission, in the manual run, this powershell script ran well and it enabled TCP protocol.
Because I need to automate this process using C# code, so I have written following code and ran above mentioned script from Windows Application with Administrative code.
    using System.Diagnostics;

    var ps1File = @"C:\scripts\enable_tcp.ps1";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            Verb = "runas",
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{ps1File}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        Process.Start(startInfo);

Here I have received an error. From the investigation, I have found that $Wmi object is returning zero ServerInstances.
When I was running script manually then I was getting {SQLEXPRESS} from output of $Wmi ServerInstances but this not happening when same script is running from code.
I think this problem will be related to code access security but not sure how to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Why are you asking this? There's no need to automate something that only happens once during installation. Using "Shared Memory" is the fastest and most secure way to connect to a local instance. If you want to allow or block remote access, open and close the firewall rule that controls port 1433

In any case, to configure networking use the correct Powershell command, Set-SqlNetworkConfiguration. The Enable the TCP protocol page shows how to enable TCP using WMI. Notice that both the instance and protocol are specified by name, not index: tcp = wmi.ServerInstances['MSSQLSERVER'].ServerProtocols['Tcp']. That's what you need to do in C# as well. Those scripts use SMO too

This somehow sounds like you are trying to use SQL EXPRESS in a manner it is not supposed to be used for. Maybe there could be better alternatives, so: what is this supposed to be used for?

Note that Verb = "runas" is ignored, unless you set UseShellExecute to true. That said, if you're already running elevated, this shouldn't matter. Note that you're using the local computer name as the MSSQL instance name.. As an aside: You can simplify (get-item env:\computername).Value to $env:computername.

If the application is running elevated, it can reference and construct a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer directly. There's no need to keep powershell around as an awkward middleman when you're effectively just using it to invoke .NET code.

Aside... maybe don't assume that mc.ServerInstances[0] will be SQLEXPRESS? On my computer, for example, it's SSIS. Although they're using the same root WMI object your PowerShell script is using quite a different technique to locate the SQLEXPRESS instance's protocols.

@PanagiotisKanavos  I need TCP protocol because of communication between Client & Server machine. I want to automate installation process of my win-form based Application. I am already using similar powershell script what you have suggested in your second link(Enable the TCP protocol) and I don’t have any problem with output of powershell script, it has enabled TCP protocol successfully when I am running it manually with elevated access. But when same script is triggered by C# code (elevated access) then it is returning wmi.ServerInstances.count = 0.

@Fildor As SQL Express is free distributable, so I am using it as back-end of Application. I need very less data-volume and my legacy database was MS SQL Express 2005. So, MS SQL Express 2019 is appropriate option for me.

I'd recommend to not make the Client access the Database directly via Network. I'd suggest to provide a DataBase API Service, that exposes an Application-Specific Interface to the Network. And then have that API Service talk to your Database.

@anoopchoudhary the code you posted is not the same as the doc examples. Have you tried to use the correct instance name at all? I'd expect 0 to return the default SQL Server instance, ie MSSQLSERVER not the named SQL Server instance, MSSQLSERVER\SQLSERVEREXPRESS. If you run this on a dev machine that had SQL Server Developer and Express installed, you have no idea what you're connecting to. And unless you change the defaults, only Shared Memory is enabled

@mklement0    Thanks for suggestion. My application is already running with elevated access. Even changing UseShellExecute = true, did not make any difference in the output.

@PanagiotisKanavos I got following $wmi output from manual powershell run.
ConnectionSettings : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.WmiConnectionInfo
Services           : {MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS, SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS, SQLBrowser}
ClientProtocols    : {np, sm, tcp}
ServerInstances    : {SQLEXPRESS}
I got following $wmi output from c# powershell run.
ConnectionSettings : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.WmiConnectionInfo
Services           : {MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS, SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS, SQLBrowser}
ClientProtocols    : {np, sm, tcp}
ServerInstances    : {}

@Fildor At this stage of new version release, it is too expensive to change the architecture. In older version, I have provided instruction for user to manually change TCP protocol through Configuration Manager.
